# Todos los titulos se vuelven links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, django, django-views

Tengo un template en django, el cual hereda de otro template que maneja los perfiles de mi webpage. El problema es que por alguna razón, todos los tags de html aparecen rodeados de <a> sin ninguna razón aparente. No se si es el bootstrap o el django el que causa el error.

Tengo:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div class="row m-3">
                <div>
                    <div class="profile-head">
                        <h5>
                            {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
                        </h5>
                        <h6>
                            {{user.email}}
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 pr-4 pb-3">
                    <div class="profile-work">
                        <p>YOUR PROFILE</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'user:profile-view' %}">Profile Page</a><br />
                        <a href="">Edit Account Info</a><br />
                        <a href="">Change Password</a><br />
                        <a href="">Forgot Password</a><br /><br />
                        <p>INFORMATION</p>
                        <a href="{% url 'user:order-history' %}">Order History</a><br />
                        <a href="">Billing Addresses</a><br />
                        <a href="">Shipping Addresses</br>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9 card p-3">
                    {% block profile-card %}
                    
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

en mi página base, la cual extiende a una que maneja el nav y footer (casi seguro que el problema no esta allí

y tengo

```
{% extends 'userInfo/profile-page.html' %}

{% block profile-card %}

<div>

    <h3>Order History</h3>

    <div class="list-group">

        {% for order in past_orders %}

        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
            <h6>
                Ordered on {{order.ordered_date.date}} at {{order.ordered_date.time}}
            </h6>
            <a href="#">
                See what you bought
            </a>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock%}
```

en la página que es mayor víctima del problema, a alguien mas le ha pasado esto? al renderizar todos los elementos del segundo bloque de código se rodean de links sin razón aparente.

Comment: Hola. Si copiaste el código html, tal cual lo usas, el error está en que el elemento `<a href="">Shipping Addresses</br>` no tiene etiqueta de cierre. Le falta `</a>` de ahí en adelante todo va a quedar anidado en ese **anchor**

Answer (score 2):

Revisa las etiquetas de links `<a href="">` esten cerradas adecuadamente con `</a>`. Chequeando encuentro la ultima de la lista, que no lo esta, corrigelo para que ese link termine alli y no se expanda al resto del documento:

```
<a href="">Shipping Addresses</a></br>
```

Comment: Uff q crack, muchas gracias, la verdad no me habia fijado en lo absoluto